# 8 duplicate symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios

My app was working fine but after some modification I am getting following error please help me ......

```
           duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MBThirdViewController.nameLabel1 in:
           /Users/major/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sideMenu- bslwsbjqbjtkojeslptbkyhajajv/Build/Intermediates/sideMenu.build/Debug-         iphonesimulator/sideMenu.build/Objects-normal/i386/MBThirdViewController- D5D149C1AA17C975.o
           duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MBThirdViewController.phoneLabel1 in:
           /Users/major/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sideMenu-bslwsbjqbjtkojeslptbkyhajajv/Build/Intermediates/sideMenu.build/Debug- iphonesimulator/sideMenu.build/Objects-normal/i386/MBThirdViewController-D5D149C1AA17C975.o
            duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MBThirdViewController.emailLabel1 in:
          /Users/major/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sideMenu-bslwsbjqbjtkojeslptbkyhajajv/Build/Intermediates/sideMenu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/sideMenu.build/Objects-normal/i386/MBThirdViewController-D5D149C1AA17C975.o
            duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MBThirdViewController.photoView1 in:
            /Users/major/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sideMenu- bslwsbjqbjtkojeslptbkyhajajv/Build/Intermediates/sideMenu.build/Debug- iphonesimulator/sideMenu.build/Objects-normal/i386/MBThirdViewController- D5D149C1AA17C975.o
             duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MBThirdViewController.imageVC in:
             /Users/major/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sideMenu- bslwsbjqbjtkojeslptbkyhajajv/Build/Intermediates/sideMenu.build/Debug- iphonesimulator/sideMenu.build/Objects-normal/i386/MBThirdViewController- D5D149C1AA17C975.o
             duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MBThirdViewController.dataObject in:
            /Users/major/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sideMenu-bslwsbjqbjtkojeslptbkyhajajv/Build/Intermediates/sideMenu.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/sideMenu.build/Objects-normal/i386/MBThirdViewController-D5D149C1AA17C975.o
```

duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MBThirdViewController in:
          /Users/major/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sideMenu-bslwsbjqbjtkojeslptbkyhajajv/Build/Intermediates/sideMenu.build/Debug- iphonesimulator/sideMenu.build/Objects-normal/i386/MBThirdViewController- D5D149C1AA17C975.o
             duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MBThirdViewController in:
              /Users/major/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sideMenu- bslwsbjqbjtkojeslptbkyhajajv/Build/Intermediates/sideMenu.build/Debug- iphonesimulator/sideMenu.build/Objects-normal/i386/MBThirdViewController- D5D149C1AA17C975.o
              ld: 8 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
             clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v                to see invocation)

Comment: Somehow you have declared some variables more than once, or perhaps moved some and the build has not picked them up.  How have you declared nameLabel1?  If you think it's ok, try's build clean then rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the ViewController is not added twice in your project.
OR
you have declared same variable more than once.

> Also got to Xcode->Window->Organizer->Projects
>
> And Delete derived data

Hope that might help.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Build Setting and search for No Common Blocks and set it NO. And build again you will not get this error again.

Comment: Can you please tell me What happens when i set NO?

Comment: Great to know that it works for you @VirajPadsala. Actually when you set No Common Blocks to NO then Xcode will allow you to declare objects globally for whole code and you can access in any class.

Comment: Hey @varotariyavajsi - Hope its solved your issue. I have seen its tricky thing and works like charm for this issue :D

Answer (score 0):

check if this MBThirdViewController is added twice in your project.

OR

remove the reference to it and try adding it again to your project.